# Header, h1 and nav- making nav not movable

Tags: css, html, nav

I want to make navigation at the same level as **h1** text and make it not movable and resizable. For now navigation is acting like random RWD, going below my **h1** text, then changing display from left->right to top->bottom. I was trying to set **ul** position to static/absolute/fixed, nothing seems to work as I'd like.

JsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/26tx3t3p/1/.

HTML:

```
<header>        
    <h1 class="logo">   myexamplesite</h1>
    <nav class="primary">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">info1</a>/</li>
            <li><a href="#">info2</a>/</li>
            <li><a href="#">info3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>
```

CSS:

```
.logo{
font-size:36px;
font-weight:bold;
float: left;
display:inline-block;
}

a{
text-decoration:none;
}

.primary ul{
float:right;
display:inline-block;
}

.primary ul li{
float:left;
font-size:18px;
padding:10px 15px 0 0;
}
```

**How to make navigation to be set at beggining position, after resizing window ??
Is there a way to do it, without putting stiff margin/width values ??**

Comment: If "set at beginning position" means staying at the top of the screen (with the h1 moving below to avoid overlapping), you could try moving the `<h1>` element after the `<nav>` in your source. Since they are positioned by CSS, it should not change their appearance.

Comment: @AndrewMyers I tried, but then <nav> is above <h1> and the same thing happens but at different place. I want either nav or h1 be unreactive.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that https://jsfiddle.net/26tx3t3p/3/

i added these css

```
header {
  position:relative;
}
nav {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: No, nav is still moving after resizing, and it covers h1 text.

Comment: yes if screen is to small it covers `h1` text (you dint tell in question it shouldnt), but nav isnt moving anywhere. checked on chrome and firefox. If you say it moves, then can you please explain from where to where is nav moving for you? maybe you have additional css for header and nav?

Comment: or by moving you mean that nav isnt centered in one line with h1 text?

Comment: It changes it's location on resizing window/using smaller screen. I want  nav and h1 to be unreactive on resizing.

Comment: but then why dont you just use static width for header? or maybe i dont understand your intention correctly.

Comment: I think @norbidrak just has to set the width of the container that he doesn't  want to shrink on window resize. Try: header{width:700px;}

Comment: @EdgarsAivars I was trying to make it at least static as possible, maybe that's not possible to achieve that way.